# Feathers.js -> socket.io not listening? Wel it's not connecting

Tags: .htaccess, socket.io, feathersjs

I'm trying to launch my web application on a site at my ISP. The url for the site is in this explanation going to be 'dev.domain.com'. I uploaded the project from webstorm. The project is build from scratch following the 'Your first App' documentation from feathersjs.

After uploading, I still had the default apache webpage the ISP gave. Cause: index.html is in public. So what I did was make a .htaccess with this content

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /public/([^\s?]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,NE,R=302]

RewriteRule ^((?!public/).*)$ public/$1 [L,NC]
```

Now the application is loading. Then I had problems that socket.io.js was not found. This was being caused by this line in the index.html file

```
<script src="socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

So I searched for a solution and found the socket.io.js in the 'node-modules\socket.io-client\dist' directory. I copied it to 'assets\scripts\js' and adjusted the link above to that folder. With 'npm start' all is still working.

Also, since I remembered the 'config\default.json' has specific information, I changed that to match too (I don't know yet how to trigger the production.json'). The server there now is also 'dev.domain.com' and the port is changed to 80.

When I now go to my site, it loads, but no data is collected yet and there are still 404 errors which come from 'http://dev.domain.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=.....'

**Question**

What needs to be done to solve this last part?

**Solving**

So, I've found that the application isn't connected to the socket, well that would be obvious with the error, but if you're not connected then the call will of course fail. I put this code in in my 'app.js' to verify the connection

```
const socket = io.connect('http://dev.domain.com);
alert(socket.connected);
```

It returns false. The url is the same as the server name in the default.json so now best to see if the socket is listening.

So then I tried a 'dirty' method, just to see if it works. I made the folder 'public\socket.io' and placed the 'socket.io.js' in that. Then it it came with an access error which I solved by adding '+Indexes' in the '.htaccess' It results in this message in the log

```
[Sun Mar 19 15:11:19 2017] [error] [client 77.174.123.8] ModSecurity: Access denied with code 501 (phase 2). Match of "rx (?:^(?:application\\\\/x-www-form-urlencoded(?:;(?:\\\\s?charset\\\\s?=\\\\s?[\\\\w\\\\d\\\\-]{1,18})?)??$|multipart/form-data;)|text/xml)" against "REQUEST_HEADERS:Content-type" required. [file "/etc/httpd/modsecurity.d/modsecurity_crs_30_http_policy.conf"] [line "69"] [id "960010"] [msg "Request content type is not allowed by policy"] [severity "WARNING"] [tag "POLICY/ENCODING_NOT_ALLOWED"] [hostname "dev.domain.com"] [uri "/socket.io/"] [unique_id "WM6Rh1TxsZYAAegdFkkAAAAU"]
```

Leaving this method for now, looking on for a different route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My ISP doesn't allow hosting of this sort of stuff. So I'm closing the question. I'll host it my self, or get a hoster that does have the option or get a hosted docker image.